# docker image error using docker container in scala

Tags: scala, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting the following error

```
[2017-03-07 15:46:00 UTC][environment:dev-b-6a8b4ad] No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/eb_deployer-0.6.6/lib/eb_deployer/eb_environment.rb:135:in `block in with_polling_events': Elasticbeanstalk instance provision failed (maybe a problem with your .ebextension files). The original message: [Instance: i-0b1228876f73ca7a9,i-0e959009aaaa54638,i-07aff1e0aca24a51f] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.  (RuntimeError)
```

my build.sbt

```
...
dockerBaseImage := "java:8"

dockerExposedPorts := Seq(5000)

lazy val packageDocker = taskKey[Unit]("Create Docker zip fileAdd packageDocker ")
packageDocker <<= packageDocker.dependsOn(stage in config("docker"))
packageDocker := {
  val targetDirectory = (baseDirectory in Compile).value / "target" / "aws"
  val inputs = Path.allSubpaths((stage in config("docker")).value) ++
    Seq((baseDirectory in Compile).value / "config" / "Dockerrun.aws.json" -> "Dockerrun.aws.json",
      (baseDirectory in Compile).value / "config" / "ebextensions" / "autoscale.config" -> ".ebextensions/autoscale.config",
      (baseDirectory in Compile).value / "config" / "ebextensions" / "nginx.config" -> ".ebextensions/nginx.config")
  val zipName = name.value
  val output: File = targetDirectory / (zipName + ".zip")
  ZipHelper.zip(inputs, output)
  println("Built docker zip: " + "'" + output.toPath + "'")
}
```

my Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Logging": "/opt/docker/logs"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to deploy my EB application through the eb cli:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-0eafcb4a345s9cc4a43] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: No Docker image specified in either Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. Abort deployment.
```

I had forgotten to specify an artifact since I wanted to deploy a ZIP file instead of the project folder.  I fixed this by adding the artifact to my `config.yml` file in the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder:

```
    branch-defaults:
      default:
        environment: <env_name>
    deploy:
      artifact: <zip_name>.zip
    global:
      application_name: <app_name>
      default_ec2_keyname: <ec2_key_name>
      default_platform: Docker 1.12.6
      default_region: us-east-1
      profile: null
      sc: null
```

More information here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact

I hope you are encountering the same issue and this fixes it!